# connecting to mysql using php - php seems to be waiting forever

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just starting learning php and I wrote following code:

```
<?php
echo "starting";
$link = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'abc123', 'phptest');

if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
}
else
{
    echo "it worked!";
}
echo "finished";
?>
```

all I get is

starting

as my output. I got mysql installed and it runs on localhost alright. I verified it using:

```
mod@mod-Inspiron-N5110:/var/www# mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=abc123
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 41
Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use phptest
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
```

Please help!

Comment: have you tried removing the @ symbol and checking the logs for more info? plus try to get the errors with [mysql-error](http://my1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Comment: @ is used to suppress warnings... remove it and it will show the error it is getting on the page... then post the error here

Comment: What the above 2 people said

Comment: Really sorry for the trouble I caused. Didn't know that I should download a mysql module with php. Installed it and now it's working fine.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for, we all learn somewhere.... and on a positive note you're starting with MySQLi rather than the older deprecated MySQL extension.... so make sure you find tutorials that teach about prepared statements and bind variables

Comment: But a couple of tips as you're just starting to learn: __always__ enable error logging when developing, and __never__ use `@` to suppress errors (no matter what you find on the interweb that uses it) unless you know exactly what you're doing